# Fetch data from localstorage/Hooks and then delete them

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am having a React-TypeScript project, where I am using a Dynamic Cart/Store items using Hooks and Local Storage. When the transaction is complete, in the thankYou/ page, I would like to display the items that we have purchased and then immediately remove/empty the cart for a new transaction.

This is my thankyou/ page:

```
const cart = useContext(CartContext);
....
....
{
    cart.cartItems.map(product => (
        <React.Fragment key={product.id}>
            <Col className="col-6">
                <Image src={product.photo} width="60" height="60" />
                <b>{{product.name}}</b>
            </Col>
            <Col className="col-2">{product.quantity}</Col>
            <Col className="col-2">
                {product.price}
            </Col>
         </React.Fragment>
     )
     )
}
```

I am doing this right now:

```
<Anchor to="/" onClick={() => cart.clearCart()}>Continue Shopping</Anchor>
```

Which is a link which clears the cart when on clicked.

My intention: I would like to clear the cart content along with the Hook whenever the thankYou/ page is loaded but also to capture the items and print it before doing this.

What I have tried-

- using a useEffect() have cleared the cart contents when page is loaded, but this is resulting in an empty cart.
- localStorage -> Since the hook internally is using the same concept, creating a new one would be redundant and difficult to manage

I am using context similar to [this](https://github.com/AlexSegen/react-shopping-cart/tree/master/src/contexts). Let me know how do I capture the items, print it and then delete/reset the cart for a new transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your cart items in a state when landing on Thank You Page,

```
const cart = useContext(CartContext);
const [items] = useState(cart.cartItems);

useEffect(() => {
  cart.clearCart(); // clear cart once we have the items
}, [items]);
```

And then clear the cart once items are set (`useEffect()`)